# Views feed permissions

Tags: 7, views, users, feeds

I have a view that has a feed view. When I try to access the feed URL as an Anonymous user it does not show any items only the feed title, but when I try to access it as admin it show items, so, I'm sure it is permissions issue.

I tried to set the Access settings of the feed as shown in the screen shot:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong?!

Comment: This is not a Views configuration problem (if it were, your anon wouldn't even be able to see the title of the View).  It sounds like your user doesn't have permission to view the actual items in the feed.   Are the items published?

Comment: Do you have any other modules that could affect access permissions to nodes? Can you test and switch to a Drupal standard theme (e.g. bartik) to discard it's something theme based?